# Scaling BufferedImage and writing to file

Tags: java

I don't know how to scale BufferedImage, to get an image that will be available to write into file. I want to use that Scaled image to throw into canvas, because size of buffered window will change, and it depends on some parameters, but firstly i want to be able to write to file. how can i easly make it?

My code:

Paint just using some matrix to put pixels in right way (that works good, just to show how it looks like)

```
public Paint(Run run, boolean kConst)
    {
        imageCALA = new BufferedImage(run.xRange, run.yRange+areaForText, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        imageStates= new BufferedImage(run.xRange, run.yRange+areaForText, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        imageStrategies= new BufferedImage(run.xRange, run.yRange+areaForText, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        imagekD= new BufferedImage(run.xRange, run.yRange+areaForText, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        for (int i=0; i<run.xRange; i++)
            for ( int j=0 ; j<run.yRange+areaForText; j++)
            {
                if (run.temporary[i][j].cellEmpty)
                {
                    imageCALA.setRGB(i, j, Color.WHITE.getRGB());
                    imageStates.setRGB(i, j, Color.WHITE.getRGB());
                    imageStrategies.setRGB(i, j, Color.WHITE.getRGB());
                    imagekD.setRGB(i, j, Color.WHITE.getRGB());
                }
                else {
                    if ( run.temporary[i][j].learningAutomata)
                        imageStrategies.setRGB(i, j, Color.MAGENTA.getRGB());

                    if ( run.temporary[i][j].learningAutomata && run.temporary[i][j].sharingPayout) 
                        imageCALA.setRGB(i, j, Color.RED.getRGB());
                    if ( run.temporary[i][j].state=='C')
                        imageStates.setRGB(i, j, Color.RED.getRGB());
                    if ( run.temporary[i][j].strategy.buffor=='C')
                        imageStrategies.setRGB(i, j, Color.RED.getRGB());


                    if (run.temporary[i][j].learningAutomata && !run.temporary[i][j].sharingPayout)
                        imageCALA.setRGB(i, j, Color.ORANGE.getRGB());
                    if (run.temporary[i][j].strategy.buffor=='P')
                        imageStrategies.setRGB(i, j, Color.ORANGE.getRGB());

                    if (!kConst)
                        for (int c=0; c<8; c++)
                        {
                            if (run.temporary[i][j].strategy.kMax==c)
                            {
                                int g = 100;
                                int b = 0;
                                int con =40;

                                int p = (Color.ORANGE.getAlpha()<<24) | (Color.ORANGE.getRed()<<16)
                                | (g+(con*c)<<8) | b+(con*b);   

                                imagekD.setRGB(i, j, p);
                            }
                        }
                    else if (kConst)
                        imagekD.setRGB(i, j, Color.ORANGE.getRGB());
                    else 
                        imagekD.setRGB(i, j, Color.WHITE.getRGB());

                    if (!run.temporary[i][j].learningAutomata && run.temporary[i][j].sharingPayout)
                        imageCALA.setRGB(i, j, Color.BLUE.getRGB());
                    if (run.temporary[i][j].state=='D')
                        imageStates.setRGB(i, j, Color.BLUE.getRGB());
                    if (run.temporary[i][j].strategy.buffor=='D')
                    {
                        imageStrategies.setRGB(i, j, Color.BLUE.getRGB());
                    }

                    if (!run.temporary[i][j].learningAutomata && !run.temporary[i][j].sharingPayout)
                        imageCALA.setRGB(i, j, Color.GREEN.getRGB());
                    if (run.temporary[i][j].strategy.buffor=='K')
                        imageStrategies.setRGB(i, j, Color.GREEN.getRGB());

                }
            }
    }

public void PrintToFile(File fCALA, File fStates, File fStrategies,File fkD) throws IOException
    {

        ImageIO.write(imageCALA, "png", fCALA);
        ImageIO.write(imageStates, "png", fStates);
        ImageIO.write(imageStrategies, "png", fStrategies);
        ImageIO.write(imagekD, "png", fkD);
    }
```

and some try section in my main class

```
   try 
            {
                paint.PrintToFile(new File("Image\\outputCALA.png"), new File("Image\\outputStates.png")
                        , new File("Image\\outputStrategies.png"), new File("Image\\outputkD.png"));
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("error"+e);
            }
```

Comment: You are writing to file `ImageIO.write...` so what is the issue?

Comment: but i want to scale it into some bigger resolution